# Auto restart/restore custom shell in windows xp

Tags: windows, shell, google-chrome, kiosk

I have a web-app and want to use it in kiosk mode.
Now I'm using chrome --kiosk mode as Windows XP custom shell. Also I added some restrictions to user with SteadyState.

But how can I prevent Alt+F4 in chrome? Or how to auto-restart custom shell after closing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved with "Advanced Internet Kiosk" program. It allows to block keyboard keys. I blocked most of keys and there is no hotkeys in browser or windows system except F5 and numeric keypad. :)